# Can't enable shell-escape

Tags: pdftex, texlive, windows, gnuplot, shell-escape

I've been trying to add the --shell-escape argument to my `pdflatex`, and right about nothing works. I'll summarize what I've done so far:

1. Add --shell-escape to existing `pdflatex.exe`
2. Add --shell-escape to `\texlive\2013\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe`
3. The console either gets stuck at "`ABD: EveryShipout initializing macrosgnuplot not recognized`", or
4. "`Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled. (gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..`", or
5. TeXworks produces no PDF
6. I have also tried running different compilers such as `miktex-pdftex.exe`, `pdftex.exe`, etc.
7. I'm running the latest MikTeX / TeX distributions, packages, etc. (just updated *everything* in my TeX Live Manager)

This only seems to be a big deal when I run anything `GNUplot` related.

What's going on here?

[image: ScreenshotOfArgumentsPdflatex]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To long for a comment. Run this document with --shell-escape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{echo "hallo"}
blub
\end{document}
```

Then check the log file. If you found there`runsystem(echo "hallo")...disabled (restricted)` 
then `--shell-escape` has not been activated. If the message is `runsystem(echo "hallo")...executed.` then everything works and your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: `runsystem(echo "hallo")...executed.`...

However, when I try to GNUplot, it tells me:

`Package gnuplottex Warning: Shell escape not enabled.
(gnuplottex)                You'll need to convert the graphs yourself..`

While within the log file itself it also shows: 

`runsystem(rm -f w18-test-2014430619.tex)...executed.` I'm assuming this line also means that --shell-escape works as intended? @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: At least you now know that you have been looking at the wrong places for a solution. Did you load the package with the miktex option `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`?

Comment: Yes @Ulrike Fischer