# Can't make Python package work

Tags: python

I'm a Windows user and I use `MiKTeX` and TeXstudio. Not long ago I tried to use [gnuplottex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311460/how-to-use-gnuplottex). In the process I ran into problems and gave up and did not understand the essence of.
Yesterday i tried to compile example of `python` package and got error

```
I can't find file `pytex.py.out'.
```

Here is example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hello, Python-inside-\LaTeX!}
\begin{python}
print r'\begin{verbatim}
import this
print r'\end{verbatim}
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

At the moment I realized that every thing, which need `--shell-escape` does not work. Through [this advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/cant-enable-shell-escape) I checked that `--shell-escape` is enabled.
Summing up all this information: I totally don't understand what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a syntax error.  Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}
\section*{Hello, Python-inside-\LaTeX!}
\begin{python}[Code.py]
    print("Hello again.")
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

Where Code.py contains:

```
# Test python code
print "Hello World!"
```

And run with (or equivalent):

```
pdflatex -shell-escape FileName.tex
```

This should first insert the python code from Code.py and then the code between the begin and end statements.

Comment: i got the same with this

Answer (score 0):

`pytex.py.out` is not being generated because your Python code is generating an error due to the unclosed single quotes in the begin/end verbatim lines.

Here's a corrected version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
\section*{Hello, Python-inside-\LaTeX!}
\begin{python}
print r'\begin{verbatim}'
import this
print r'\end{verbatim}'
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

However, if you want to integrate Python into your LaTeX document I recommend the [pythontex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) package, as it's more powerful and flexible than the simple `python` package.

Comment: i got the same , when i try to compile it on my computer. But in sharelatex.com it compiled fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Python installed on your computer and in your `PATH`?  Is a `pytex.py.err` file being generated in the directory where you're compiling your latex file?

Comment: Damn.Now i did it,i downloaded python 3.5.2 and choosed in the installer add Python in PATH. That's it?

Comment: Probably.  As long as latex (via --shell-escape) can find the Python executable. Though that may depend on your OS, latex setting, etc.

Comment: Apparently,latex did not find Python.I got a feeling that in my case latex with shell work wrong and cant find things.Can i link it manually?